# How do I access blob storage sub containers in my ASP.NET Core web application?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I've created a solution to access my container contents within my asp.net core 3.1 application and return that contents as a list to my view.  At the moment the application access data in the root container which is called `upload`, however, this container has many sub containers and I would like to list the blobs in a specific one called `1799`.

So, instead of accessing `upload` and showing me the full contents of that container, I want to access `upload/1799` and list all the blobs within that container.

I cannot see of anyway to add this sub container to my method and allow this to happen, can anyone help?

Here is my code so far:

**CarController.cs**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly string accessKey = string.Empty;

        public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {    
            _configuration = configuration;
            accessKey = _configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureStorage");
        }

        [HttpGet]        
        public IActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
        var car = _carService.GetVessel(id);           

        string strContainerName = "uploads";
        string subdir = "1799";
        var filelist = new List<BlobListViewModel>();

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(accessKey);

        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(strContainerName);            
        var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs();

        foreach (var item in blobs)
        {
            filelist.Add(new BlobListViewModel
            {
                FileName = item.Name                    
            });
        }
        return View(filelist);
    }
}
```

I've hunted through all the documentation and I can't find anything related to this.

Comment: The GetBlobs method supports a "prefix" for you to supply a partial blob name.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobs?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David Browne for his comment, there is indeed a prefix option in `GetBlob()`.  THey act like mini-filters in some ways allowing you to define what properties are returned and the blob state etc.  Here is my code which has the options set to zero meaning `Default` for both `Trait` and `State`.

```
[HttpGet]        
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var car = _carService.GetVessel(id);    

    string strContainerName = "uploads";
    string subdir = "1799";

    var filelist = new List<BlobListViewModel>();

    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(accessKey);
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(strContainerName);            

    //Traits, States, Prefix
    var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs(0, 0, subdir);

    foreach (var item in blobs)
    {
        filelist.Add(new BlobListViewModel
        {
            FileName = item.Name                    
        });
    }
    return View(filelist);
}
```